# What version of iOS I have with Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6, ios8.4

How I can tell the iOS SDK version used by my Xcode? and iOS SDK version installed on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK version by Xcode can be seen in the Build Settings of your project:

[image]

To find out which iOS SDKs are installed, open the terminal and type

```
ls -lah /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

(according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html), this is the location where they're installed)

Comment: Thats right I can see that. looks logical. I am going to up vote for now. can you also try to answer my other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483310/update-ios-sdk-version-to-8-4

Comment: total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   102B Sep 28  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel   170B Nov  5  2013 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel   272B Oct 10  2013 iPhoneOS7.0.sdk

Comment: That's not true. I have on Base SDK 8.3 selected. and I can run app. on devices with iOS up to 8.3 and not 8.4. it say Ineligible Device.

Comment: the command line shows the following: drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel   136B Jul 17 19:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel   170B May 12 07:42 ..
drwxrwxr-x  9 root  wheel   306B Mar 31 23:49 iPhoneOS.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    12B Jul 17 19:49 iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -> iPhoneOS.sdk the other was for different mac :)