# Update iOS SDK version to 8.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios8.4, xcode6.3.2

I had a version of the Xcode I believe It was 6.1 with iOS SDK version 8.3.

Apple store showed that an Xcode update is available with SDK 8.4.

I updated Xcode and the new update version was 6.3.2.

I have a iPad with iOS 8.4 on it. so to run the app on it, I tried to set the Base SDK to 8.4. but, surprisingly It doesn't exists! I can only choose 8.3 with "Latest iOS" written beside it.

What can I do? And why the update said that the SDK version that is available is 8.4 since it didn't exists?!

> In the updates page in Apple store app there is a list titled "Updates
>   Installed in the Last 30 Days" and the I have Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4
>   with it. while when I open the Xcode at the welcome page it says 6.3.2
>   and Base SDK is 8.3!!!

Comment: You need Xcode 6.4 for iOS SDK 8.4.

Comment: what is the steps? when I try to download that from apple it opens it on the Apple Store app on mac. but, there is no option to download or install. the button says open!!

Comment: Which version of OS X are you on?

Comment: In the updates page in Apple store there is a list titled "Updates Installed in the Last 30 Days" and the I have Xcode 6.4 and iOS 8.4 with it. while when I open the Xcode at the welcome page it says 6.3.2 and Base SDK is 8.3!!!

Comment: That is really strange. Have you restarted your Mac since then?

Comment: This crazy. those retarded people at apple. I wasted 2.5 GB download and 4 hours. I guess I have to delete the code and re-download the 6.4

Comment: That would certainly solve the problem (maybe also the one with the iOS SDK version in your other thread). I'm really sorry for you.

Comment: downloaded xcode 6.4 and it doesn't have 8.4 sdk..wtf??

Comment: :) lol, those apple ppl. why don't you download Xcode 7.0 and have iOS 9?